# c# read a list of anonymous type occurs an error with a foreach

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone, html-agility-pack

I need to get data from this list, however when I put my foreach of a runtime error saying that the list contains null objects. But if I remove the foreach and put a breakpoint on the line where listbox.itemsSource receives the list, I see that I have the list loaded with all items correctly.

```
  var imgs = e.Document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//img[@src]")
                    .Select(img => new 
                    {
                        Link = img.Attributes["src"].Value,
                        Title = img.Attributes["alt"].Value,         

                    }).ToList(); 
                listBoxPopular.ItemsSource = imgs;

                foreach (var item in imgs)
                {
                    listBoxPopular.Items.Add(new PopularVideos(item.Title, item.Link));
                }
```

Class:

```
class PopularVideos
    {
        public PopularVideos() { }
        public PopularVideos(string titulo, string url)
        {
            Titulo = titulo;            
            BitmapImage Img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
        }

        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        public Uri Url { get; set; }
    }
```

The error is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in AppUnno.dll
```

Stack Trace:

> AppUnno.dll!AppUnno.MainPage.DownLoadCompleted(object sender, HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e) Line 58 + 0x6 bytes  C#

Comment: What's the stack trace? Where does the error occur?

Comment: My guess is that you've got an `img` tag which is missing an `alt` attribute...

Comment: @SLaks The error occurs in the selection of the nodes. If I get the foreach him to give errors.

Comment: @JonSkeet The alt attribute exists, because when I put the breakpoit I can see what is being stored and it can see the alt.

Comment: @LuizNegrini: For *every* element? Have you checked the breakpoint on every iteration of the loop? My guess is that you saw it for *one* element...

Comment: @JonSkeet When I put the breakpoint shows over 100 items caught.

Comment: @LuizNegrini: I have no idea what you mean by "over 100 items caught" I'm afraid.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: @Anirudh I do not know how to answer this question. What do I need to show?

Comment: @Anirudh AppUnno.dll!AppUnno.MainPage.DownLoadCompleted(object sender, HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e) Line 58 + 0x6 bytes C#

Comment: What's `DownLoadCompleted` line 58?

Comment: @MikeChristensen is this: HtmlWeb.LoadAsync("http://www.unnu.com/popular-music-videos", DownLoadCompleted);

Comment: What is the full stack trace? What is line 58 of that file?

Comment: @SLaks please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476917/c-sharp-htmlagilitypack-wrapp-taking-several-images-titles-and-links-windows-ph/17477328?noredirect=1#17477328