# c# HtmlAgilityPack Wrapp taking several images, titles and links Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, wrapper, html-agility-pack

How to fetch the data on [this page](http://www.unnu.com/popular-music-videos)? I need to get the image and its corresponding title and display in a list box. Using class or not. I do not know how to do, please help me!

Do not even know where to start! I've tried several things and none work, then turned into a mess, would someone guide me from the beginning.

```
var imgs = e.Document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//img[@src]")
                    .Select(img => new 
                    {
                        Link = img.Attributes["src"].Value,
                        Title = img.Attributes["alt"].Value,         

                    }).ToList(); 
                listBoxPopular.ItemsSource = imgs;

                foreach (var item in imgs)
                {
                    listBoxPopular.Items.Add(new PopularVideos(item.Title, item.Link));
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @I4V Yes, but not works. I need to learn how to fetch data from each image and title.

Comment: @I4V I've tried it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456330/c-sharp-read-a-list-of-anonymous-type-occurs-an-error-with-a-foreach but gave up because no one could explain the error. And I think that the data were being caught in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='content']")
               .Descendants("img")
               .Select(img => new
               {
                   Title = img.Attributes["alt"].Value,
                   Url = img.Attributes["src"].Value,
               })
               .ToList();
```

Comment: How to link this attributes to my listbox?

Comment: `listBox1.DisplayMember = "Title"; listBox1.DataSource = data;`

Comment: Windows phone does not work with Datasource or DisplayMember = /

Comment: I thought your question was `How to fetch the data on this page?`

Comment: Now with the breakpoint could see that the variable is loaded. But I can not instantiate objects of the class. But it was of great help! thank you